# How to recursively open file .txt in centos 7

Tags: bash, shell

I had many files which I got from the censor. Moreover,  the files increase every hour. The files consist of 3 parts, rain_date_time. How can I open each file recursively to get what's inside the file and add it to database. I have found the way to read the file one by one, yet I face difficulty in reading

---

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aLqE.png)

Comment: ----this is the sample code----


#! bin/bash

#I='cat rain_31122018_2303.txt'
#I='read -r -d ' 'RLOG <rain_31122018_2303.txt || [[$RLOG]]'
FILE=rain_31122018_2330.txt
I=$(tr -d '\0' <$FILE)
CH=$(echo $I | cut -d '#; -f 1)
NO=$(echo $I | cut -d '#; -f 2)
DATE=$(echo $I | cut -d '#; -f 3)
TIME=$(echo $I | cut -d '#; -f 4)
RAIN=$(echo $I | cut -d '#; -f 5)

echo "ch = $CH"
echo "no = $NO"
echo "date = $DATE"
echo "time = $TIME"
echo "rain = $RAIN"

Comment: What do you mean by "recursively read a file"? Do you want to read all the files in a directory recursively?  Re-read a file every once in a while? Please be clear. And as Cyrus said, please put your code (nicely formatted) in the question, not as a comment.

Comment: Please edit your original question and paste the sample data there. It will be much more readable. Please add 4 characters (or more) indentation to get the "source code" box.

Comment: It is still not really clear what your question is? Do you just want to run your script over multiple input files? Do you need your script to detect when a new file is added in the folder?